# Which is the best, free, calendar application for Windows

Tags: calendar

I need a detailed calendar for my activities in an attempt to organize my day.
Do you have preferences for such a free program?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your question isn't a good fit here. We generally avoid questions whose answers are primarily based on opinion rather than fact. If you edit your question to explain what *exactly* you're looking for in a calendar, we'll be better able to help. What features are you looking for? Best for what? Which calendars have you tried already, and what did you like / dislike about them? In the mean time, why not take a look at our "help" pages? They'll give you a better idea of how things work around here.

Comment: Hi, I would love an application of a pleasant interface that can be modified. I need to take notes for my tasks. I need to use pictures from time to time. I also need a reliable application for list making... other than Excel.

Comment: Please rewrite your Question to include your requirements. Look for the Edit button or link. Be *very specific*. Explain how certain products *specifically* do nor meet those needs. Edit the title as well to summarize you particular needs rather than asking for "the best".